# Action on group of features from layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I need to implement a rename action on a selected group of features in a certain order. The idea is that I would rename one feature and then select the features that are 'next in line' and execute a rename function (if i name the first one A then the next would be B, C, D, etc). My problem is that a python layer action is run on a single feature and I'm not sure that the feature sequence in which the action is done is also the proper one. I would like to avoid as much user input as possible.

Could you advise me the best way to do this? I need to distribute the solution to my user group.

QGIS version 2.8.1

Comment: Note: if I could pass the list of feature ID's on to my postgis db, then my problem would be solved. How to pass the ID's of selected features to the db using a UI action?

Comment: You can use the field calculator to update an entire table in one go.